# Matrices in Real Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've been learning Clifford algebra from [this lecture notes](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ejmf/Teaching/Lectures/Majorana.pdf).

Let $V$ be a complex vector space. Then, a choice of basis means that we make the identification $V\cong\mathbb{C}^{n}$. We can view it as a real $2n$-dimensional vector space $V_{\mathbb{R}}$ with the $\mathbb{R}$-basis $\left\{\mathbf{e}_{1},\cdots,\mathbf{e}_{n},i\mathbf{e}_{1},\cdots,i\mathbf{e}_{n}\right\}$. In this basis, the complex structure can be expressed as the matrix $$I=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -_{n\times n}\\
_{n\times n} & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}.$$

If $V$ possesses a Hermitian form $\langle\,\,\,,\,\,\,\rangle:V\times V\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, then one can define the Hermitian matrix $\mathbf{A}$: $$\langle\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\rangle\equiv\mathbf{u}^{\dagger}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{v},$$

where $\mathbf{A}^{\dagger}=A$.

If $V$ possesses a $\mathbb{C}$-bilinear form $\left(\,\,\,,\,\,\,\right):V\times V\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, then one can define the matrix $\mathbf{B}$: $$\left(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\right)\equiv\mathbf{u}^{T}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{v},$$

where $\mathbf{B}^{T}=\mathbf{B}$ if $\left(\,\,\,,\,\,\,\right)$ is symmetric and $\mathbf{B}^{T}=-\mathbf{B}$ if $\left(\,\,\,,\,\,\,\right)$ is anti-symmetric.

For any operator $\mathbf{M}$ in $V$, we can write it as $M=M_{1}+iM_{2}$ in $V_{\mathbb{R}}$, where $M_{1}$ and $M_{2}$ are linear operators in $\mathrm{span}_{\mathbb{R}}\left\{\mathbf{e}_{1},\cdots,\mathbf{e}_{n}\right\}$.

Similarly, any vector $\mathbf{w}\in V$ can be written as $w=\sum_{k}x^{k}\mathbf{e}_{k}+\sum_{k}y^{k}i\mathbf{e}_{k}\in V_{\mathbb{R}}=\mathrm{span}_{\mathbb{R}}\left\{\mathbf{e}_{1},\cdots,\mathbf{e}_{n},i\mathbf{e}_{1},\cdots,i\mathbf{e}_{n}\right\}$.

Then, from the expression of $Mw$, one can read off the matrix expression

$$\mathbf{M}_{\mathbb{R}}\equiv\begin{pmatrix}
M_{1} & -M_{2}\\
M_{2} & M_{1}\\
\end{pmatrix},$$

which acts on $\mathrm{span}_{\mathbb{R}}\left\{\mathbf{e}_{1},\cdots,\mathbf{e}_{n},i\mathbf{e}_{1},\cdots,i\mathbf{e}_{n}\right\}$.

However, in the lecture notes, the expression of the Hermitian matrix $\mathbf{A}$ and the symmetric(anti-symmetric) matrix $\mathbf{B}$ are given in the following form: $$\mathbf{A}_{\mathbb{R}}=\begin{pmatrix}
A & -iA\\
iA & A\\
\end{pmatrix}\quad\mathrm{and}\quad\mathbf{B}_{\mathbb{R}}=\begin{pmatrix}
B & iB\\
-iB & -B\\
\end{pmatrix}.$$

This doesn't make sense to me. Please help me figure out where I am wrong.